# Simple doctrine query -> one specific row and column

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

I do have a table called `"tax"` with two column `"id | tax_value"`. I can list the table with an `foreach` very well.

Now my question, how does the code look like when I just want to have 
one specfic row and column in the php code? I don't want it in the query!!!

for example:

```
column 2 (tax_value)

row 1.
```

The query gives me an array, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In TaxTable.class.php:

```
public function getOneById($id)
{
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()->select("t.tax_value")
                                 ->from("tax t")
                                 ->where("t.id = ?", $id)
                                 ->fetchOne();
    return $q;
}
```

In action:

```
public function executeTaxView(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    $this->tax = TaxTable::getInstance()->getOneById($request->getParameter("id"));
    $this->forward404Unless($this->tax);
}
```

in taxViewSucess.php:

```
  Tax Value: <b><?php echo $tax->getTaxValue();?></b>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Doctrine::HYDRATE_SINGLE_SCALAR` when fetching a single row with a single column in your select statement:

```
$total = Doctrine_Query::create()->from('Products p')
        ->select('SUM(p.amount) as total')
        ->where('p.category_id = ?', $categoryId)
        ->fetchOne(array(), Doctrine::HYDRATE_SINGLE_SCALAR);
// $total is now a single value, eg. 12
```

Example uses a imaginary Product table with categories and selects the amount of products for a certain category.

How you use this query in symfony depends on your needs: in a table class, model class, action, ..

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Doctrine_Query](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/1.2/doctrine/doctrine_query.html), then you can use fetchOne to grab one single row.  Furthermore it's been a bit since I've used Doctrine 1, but I'm almost certain with Doctrine_Query you can set the field selection list to one column.